# Trouble with ADAL and Microsoft Graph API in Python: Python API call failed

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Python to access the Microsoft Graph API for user data using the **`adal`** library. However, I'm encountering an issue when running my script. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import requests
import adal

# Define your Microsoft Azure AD app details

client_id = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
client_secret = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
tenant_id = 'YOUR_TENANT_ID'
resource_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'

# Define the URL for the Microsoft Graph API to get the logged-in user's details

graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'

# Create a function to acquire an access token

def get_access_token():
authority_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D'
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_url, client_id, client_secret)
return token.get('accessToken')

# Make a request to the Microsoft Graph API

def get_user_details(access_token):
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

    response = requests.get(graph_url, headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        user_data = response.json()
        print("User Details:")
        print(f"Display Name: {user_data.get('displayName')}")
        print(f"Email: {user_data.get('userPrincipalName')}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to get user details. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
File "graph.py", line 2, in <module>     import adal   File
"...../python/site-packages/adal/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>   
from .authentication_context import AuthenticationContext   File
"...../python/site-packages/adal/authentication_context.py", line 34,
in <module>     from .token_request import TokenRequest   File
"...../python/site-packages/adal/token_request.py", line 34, in
<module>     from . import self_signed_jwt   File
"...../python/site-packages/adal/self_signed_jwt.py", line 35, in
<module>     import jwt   File
"...../python/site-packages/jwt/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>    
from .api_jwk import PyJWK, PyJWKSet   File
"...../python/site-packages/jwt/api_jwk.py", line 7, in <module>    
from .algorithms import get_default_algorithms, has_crypto,
requires_cryptography   File
"...../python/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 12, in <module>  
from .utils import (   File "...../python/site-packages/jwt/utils.py",
line 7, in <module>     from
cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec import EllipticCurve  
File
"...../python/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py",
line 11, in <module>     from cryptography.hazmat._oid import
ObjectIdentifier   File
"...../python/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/_oid.py", line 9, in
<module>     from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import (
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed
```

How can I resolve this issue and successfully access the Microsoft Graph API using **`adal`** in Python?

Comment: The support for adal ended in June 2023. The recommended library to use now is MSAL. See this link for the required information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-migration. Please try the approach using msal and update the question with the new code if you still face any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with *@Anupam Chand*, you have to make use of MSAL
library to achieve your requirement.

> **Note** that: If you are generating access token using Client Credential flow then there is no user interaction involved. To get the signed in user details you have to make use of user interactive flows.

If you want to use Client Credential flow, then pass the graph_url as `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID`:

```py
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
import requests

clientID = 'ClientID'
clientSecret = 'ClientSecret'
scopes= ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"] 
tenantID = 'TenantID'
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID,clientSecret,authority=authority)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
access_token = result.get("access_token")
print(access_token)

graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
response = requests.get(graph_url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    user_data = response.json()
    print(user_data)
else:
    print('Error:', response.status_code, response.text)
```

[image]

**User Interactive flow:**: To get signed in user details

```py
import msal

client_id = 'ClientID'
tenant_id = 'TenantID'
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority)
result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes)
access_token = result['access_token']
print(access_token)

graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
response = requests.get(graph_url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    user_data = response.json()
    print(user_data)
else:
    print('Error:', response.status_code, response.text)
```

User must sign-in like below:

[image]

[image]

**The signed in user details are displayed successfully:**

[image]